# Подсказки в редакторе кода к функциям

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то в SQL Developer включить подсказки, которые показывали бы какие аргументы нужно писать для любой используемой функции?

Наподобие формул в Excel:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Допполнил, как выглядит сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Подсказки для параметров функций и процедур работают также, как и для столбцов таблиц.

Включить:

> Tools -> Preferences -> Code Editor -> Completion Insight

В окне редактора кода при установленном соединении начните набирать, и при нажатой клавише контроля нажмите пробел:

```
begin
    proc(
      ---^^^ Ctrl+Space
```

---

PS Внутренние SQL функции (`substr`, `instr`, итд) интегрированны в кернел, на них нет ни исходников, ни информации в словарх БД. SQL Developer берёт информацию о параметрах из словарей БД, поэтому информацию о параметрах внутренних SQL функций он не предлагает.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Данная настройка была включена, но при нажатии ctrl+space после написания какой-либо функции только предлагает из выпадающего списка выбрать любой из существующих столбцов таблицы, параметры функции также как и раньше не отображаются.

Comment: Покажите в вопросе, как вы делаете.

Comment: Добавил фото, которое получается после нажатия сочетания клавиш ctrl+space

Comment: Посмотрел ваш скриншот. По моему то, что вы пытаетесь достичь невозможно. Внутренние SQL функции (substr, instr, итд) интегрированны  в кернел, на них нет в БД ни исходников,  ни информации в словарх, др.сл. SQL Developer*у неоткуда взять информацию о параметрах, он и предлагет самый лучший вариант - подставить значения колонок для параметров.

Comment: @V4n33f Попробуйте с польльзователскими функциями, после begin начинайте писать add_job_history ( ....

Comment: @V4n33f Если мой ответ не предложил решения, которое вы ожидали, то всё равно хотел бы попросить вас его принять. Ответ - _нет, так не работает_, это тоже полезный ответ. Посмотрите, сколько времени мы потратили на оформление вопроса/ответа и затем на комментарии. Если кто-то зайдёт в эту тему из поиска, и на отказе от дальнейших попыток найти решение сэкономит время, то для него это тема будет очень полезной.